# nested serializers in Django

Tags: django

I have 4 models in my Django app - Schools, Universities, ExecutiveHeads and Students. There is a one to many relationship between School/University and ExecutiveHeads/Students. A student/executive head can be part of either a school or university. There can be multiple executive heads and students in a college or university. The models are defined as follows -

```
Class University(model.Models):

  established_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  established_by = models.TextField()
  name = models.TextField()

Class School(model.Models):

  established_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  established_by = models.TextField()
  name = models.TextField()
  associated_university = models.ForeignKey(University,  null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

Class ExecutiveHeads(model.Models):

  name = models.TextField()
  dob = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  limit = models.Q(app_label=‘school’, model=‘School’) | models.Q(app_label=‘university’, model=‘University’)
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, max_length=8, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=limit)
  institute_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  institute_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', ‘institute_id’)

Class Students(model.Models):

  name = models.TextField()
  dob = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  graduation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  limit = models.Q(app_label=‘school’, model=‘School’) | models.Q(app_label=‘university’, model=‘University’)
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, max_length=8, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=limit)
  institute_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  institute_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', ‘institute_id’)
```

I have the following serializers defined as shown [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) -

```
class ExecutiveHeadsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  Class Meta:
    model = ExecutiveHead
    fields = ‘__all__’

class  Students(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  Class Meta:
    model = Students
    fields = ‘__all__’


Class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  students =  Students(many=True)
  executives =  ExecutiveHeads(many=True)
  class Meta:
    model = School
    fields = ('established_at', 'established_by', 'name', 'associated_university’, ‘students’ , ‘executives’)
```

When a GET is called on School or university, I want the response to also return all the associated ExecutiveHeads and Students. I have included the student and executive head serializers in school/university serializer to achieve that. However, this doesn't work and I get only school info in return. Any pointers on how to do get students and executive heads info is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation) field to the School model to enable reverse relation:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

Class School(model.Models):    
  established_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  established_by = models.TextField()
  name = models.TextField()
  associated_university = models.ForeignKey(University,  null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  students = GenericRelation(Students)
  executives = GenericRelation(ExecutiveHeads)
```

Also In `serializers` module, `Students` serializer name clashed with model name. Rename your serializer:

```
class  StudentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  Class Meta:
    model = Students
    fields = ‘__all__’

Class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  students =  StudentsSerializer(many=True)
  executives =  ExecutiveHeads(many=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @neverwalkaloner. I was getting the following error after doing what your suggested - 

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'object_id' into field. Choices are: artifact_id, artifact_object, content_type, content_type_id, id, key, value`

I made the following changes and things started working as expected - 

`students =  StudentsSerializer(many=True, object_id_field='institute_id', content_type_field='content_type')
executives =  ExecutiveHeads(many=True, object_id_field='institute_id', content_type_field='content_type')`